# How to create app to allow posts to message board with push notifications?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app that will allow users to post to a message board, and that post send out to all users with the app and push notifications enabled.

I'm a competent programmer, so searching and implementing code isn't the problem. I'm just very new to Android app development, and I'm getting hung up on the messaging aspect of it.

Is it easier to use an API of a message board, or is there some hidden code I'm missing that allows messages to be sent out as push notifications.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I am trying to do the same, starting with no push notifications.